# Erro ao tentar chamar mais de uma função no onPress

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Eu tenho um `Button` com um `onPress`

Se coloco esse `onPress` assim:

```
onPress={() => request.manifestacaoAnonima(
    this.state.email,
    this.state.selected,
    this.state.manifesto,
    this.state.tipomanifestacao,
    this.state.tipopessoa,
    this.state.latitude,
    this.state.longitude,
    this.state.endereco,
    this.state.numero,
    this.state.complemento,
    this.state.bairro,
    this.state.cidade
  )}
```

Ele funciona envia os dados pra **API**, tudo ok.

Porém se tento chamar mais uma função neste mesmo `onPress`:

```
onPress={() => { request.manifestacaoAnonima(
    this.state.email,
    this.state.selected,
    this.state.manifesto,
    this.state.tipomanifestacao,
    this.state.tipopessoa,
    this.state.latitude,
    this.state.longitude,
    this.state.endereco,
    this.state.numero,
    this.state.complemento,
    this.state.bairro,
    this.state.cidade
  ), Actions.index() }
}
```

Ele executa o `Actions.index()` corretamente porém me retorna `Request failed with status code 500` no `request`

Qual pode ser o motivo?

**EDIT**

O `request` que esta chamando vem do `import request from './services/request';`

A qual possui:

```
const request = {

  let: dssenha = geraSenha(6),

  manifestacaoAnonima: (
    eeemailusuario,
    local,
    dstextomanifestacao,
    idtipomanifestacao,
    tipopessoa,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    endereco,
    numero,
    complemento,
    bairro,
    cidade
  ) => {
    axios.post('http://192.168.0.23/apiTeste/public/api/manifestacao?'
    +'dssenha='+dssenha
    +'&dstextomanifestacao='+dstextomanifestacao
    +'&eeemailusuario='+eeemailusuario
    +'&nmpessoa=Anônimo'
    +'&nrpronac='+local
    +'&tipopessoa='+tipopessoa
    +'&idtipomanifestacao='+idtipomanifestacao
    +'&latitude='+latitude
    +'&longitude='+longitude
    +'&enendereco='+endereco
    +'&nrendereco='+numero
    +'&dscomplemento='+complemento
    +'&dsbairro='+bairro
    +'&dslocalidade='+cidade
    )
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch((error) => { 
      console.log(error.message)
    });
  },
};

export default request;
```

Comment: Ele executa a index corretamente, como action é chamada de página, e vai para página ok, ele começa a me retornar o `500` no request, o qual se feito sozinho não resulta erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver assim

```
onPress={() => { Actions.principal();
                  { 
                    request.manifestacaoAnonima(
                      this.state.email,
                      this.state.selected,
                      this.state.manifesto,
                      this.state.tipomanifestacao,
                      this.state.tipopessoa,
                      this.state.latitude,
                      this.state.longitude,
                      this.state.endereco,
                      this.state.numero,
                      this.state.complemento,
                      this.state.bairro,
                      this.state.cidade
                    ) 
                 }
         }
```

Como dito pelo `Lucas Costa` tive de usar `;` no lugar da `,` e colocar o `request` entre `{}`

Mas acabei melhorando com uma função e a chamada dessa:

```
finalizaManifestacao = () => {
    Actions.index();
    this.setState({ visibleModal: null });
    { 
      this.state.anonima == 1 ?
        request.manifestacaoAnonima(
          this.state.email,
          this.state.selected,
          this.state.manifesto,
          this.state.tipomanifestacao,
          this.state.tipopessoa,
          this.state.latitude,
          this.state.longitude,
          this.state.endereco,
          this.state.numero,
          this.state.complemento,
          this.state.bairro,
          this.state.cidade
        ) : 
        request.manifestacao(
          this.state.email,
          this.state.selected,
          this.state.manifesto,
          this.state.tipomanifestacao,
          this.state.tipopessoa,
          this.state.latitude,
          this.state.longitude,
          this.state.endereco,
          this.state.numero,
          this.state.complemento,
          this.state.bairro,
          this.state.cidade,
          this.state.nome,
          this.state.cel,
          this.state.tel,
          this.state.cpf,
          this.state.tipopessoa
        ) 
    } 
  }
```

E a chamada em um botão que fica no modal

```
{this._renderButton('Sim, cadastrar', () => this.finalizaManifestacao() )}
```